# Are there still NYC popup vaccination sites for tourists? If so, where?

Tags: covid-19, new-york-city, vaccinations

I'll be traveling to NYC from abroad in a few weeks and am currently unvaccinated (I'm not a US citizen or resident, but I've already checked and will be able to enter the country).

I've read many articles ([[A]](https://www.travelandleisure.com/travel-news/nyc-covid-vaccine-available-for-tourists), [[B]](https://www.washingtonpost.com/travel/2021/05/17/vaccine-covid-nyc-dracula-travelers/), [[C]](https://www.ny1.com/nyc/all-boroughs/coronavirus/2021/05/08/city-attempts-to-bring-back-tourism-by-offering-covid-vaccine-)) mentioning that NYC would open tourist vaccination sites in tourist hotspots (Times Square, Central Park, the Brooklyn Bridge, etc) offering the J&J vaccine, but they are all from early May. I've also not found a single official reference to these mobile hubs, never mind where they'll be (Central Park is pretty big!).

So, are these mobile hubs still operational? Is there a map of where they can be found? Do I need to book a time?

If the hubs no longer exist, where could I get vaccinated?

Comment: @gerrit the J&J vaccine mentioned in the post is a single-dose one.

Answer (score 8):

According to the [New York State COVID-19 Vaccine Form](https://forms.ny.gov/s3/vaccine), which you are required to fill out prior to receiving a vaccination in the state of New York, you must "certify [...] that [you] reside in the United States."

Based on this requirement, it appears that NYC popup vaccination sites are not available to international tourists, nor would you be able to get vaccinated anywhere else in the state of New York at. Note that other states will have different eligibility requirements.

Comment: Yep, just find a US state which doesn’t have a residency requirement and you’re good to go. Washington is one such state and there’s probably others.

Answer (score 5):

As with all things relating to NYC government, [nyc.gov](https://nyc.gov/).

There's a [COVID-19 vaccination link at the top of the page](http://www.nyc.gov/vaccinecommandcenter).

The linked page in turn has a link for [a list of sites where you can get vaccinated today](https://www1.nyc.gov/site/coronavirus/vaccines/covid-19-vaccines.page#walk-up-sites).

There is also a link to a page with [the current eligibility requirements](https://www1.nyc.gov/site/doh/covid/covid-19-vaccine-eligibility.page).  There's no mention of a residency requirement, and there's an explicit disclaimer of an immigration status requirement, but there is a requirement to fill out the [New York State COVID-19 Vaccine Form](https://forms.ny.gov/s3/vaccine).  It's not clear to me how you would do that without a US address (or even with an address in a US territory such as Puerto Rico), but I suppose as a last resort you could use the address where you are staying temporarily.

Comment: According to the form, you must "certify [...] that [you] presently reside in the United States," so it looks like the New York vaccine sites are not available to international tourists.

Comment: @AndrewRay thanks, I overlooked that.  I'm still curious about Puerto Rico, though.

Comment: Presumably you would put "Puerto Rico" as the "State." US territories have ZIP codes (006XX, 007XX, 009XX for PR; 008XX for USVI; 200XX, 20200 - 20599 for DC; 96799 for AS; 96910 - 96932 for Guam; 96950 - 96952 for CNMI), so no issues there.

Comment: Interestingly in Washington you don’t have to certify that you reside in the US. You do give an address on the form but even that is optional since homeless people are allowed to get vaccinated too. NY is probably more sensitive to this given the amount of international tourism there.

Comment: @AndrewRay you _could_ put Puerto Rico as the state if it were in the "state" list, but it isn't.  As far as I can tell the only non-state entity in the list is DC.

Comment: I was able to type "Puerto Rico" into the field even though it didn't appear as an autofill. There was no indication that the value was invalid, but I didn't try to submit the form as I have no intention of getting vaccinated in New York state.

Comment: @AndrewRay I just tested that and I did submit the form.  The validation logic cleared the "state" field and prompted me to enter a valid value in it.